# How to create a derived column base on other column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have two tables. One table has product information with a column ProdNum and the second table has all the related product documents. Those prodcut document name format is like this: ProdNumxxxx.pd So all documents' five first digits are related to a ProdNum then it has letters and other number. I need to join these two tables to find the documents related to the product number. Now I can't join it on ProdNum and ProdFile because obviously they do not match. I was thinking of creating another column that will pick up the first five characters of ProdFile name and then create a column on those first five characters that way I can do JOIN on it to match the ProdNum. I have absolutely no clue how to do this. Any ideas/opinions?

Comment: or you can use a SUBSTRING function to extract the characters and then use it in the JOIN condition

Comment: Which database are you using - SQL Server or Oracle or something else?

Comment: Can you please specify the table names, column names, and include sample data as well. This information would be helpful to write the JOIN condition.

Comment: First of all thank you for a reply. I am searching on Substring and charindex right now for that matter. SQL Server. Sample Tables:
Table1
ProductInfo
  ProdNum  ProdName  ProdSoldDate
1. 45612   ABC       4/1/2012
2. 75896   CVF       5/1/2014
3. 64587   FGH       9/2/2013

Table2
ProductFiles
  ProdFileName
1. 45612_fhsdj.doc
2. 7589445_fdj_df.doc
3. 64587fdfdj.doc

Comment: You're welcome! This expression would probably work for you: WHERE <Product Information Table>.ProdNum = SUBSTRING(<Product Document Information Table>.ProdFile, 1, 5)

Comment: Ok so how would it create a derived column? should I use the where clause with Update table1 SET FileName and where clause?

Comment: I tried this doing select ProdFiles FROM ProdFileInfo WHERE ProdInfo.ProdNum = SUBSTRING(ProdFileInfo.ProdFile, 1, 5) and it returns me an error: The multi-part identifier "ProdInfo.ProdNum" could not be bound.

Comment: I see what you are saying. You are saying to do the joins and add that to the where clause. I tried that as well and it reutned me an error: "Error converting data type varchar to float."

Comment: Try: select ProdFileInfo.* FROM ProdFileInfo INNER JOIN ProdInfo ON  ProdInfo.ProdNum = CAST(SUBSTRING(ProdFileInfo.ProdFile, 1, 5) AS decimal);

Comment: Hey thank you so much, it worked. I just needed to change the datatype :D

Comment: ok I am so sorry to bother you again. I had tried this and it worked on my test table but it doesnt work on my actual table. Its returning me data conversion error: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric." and when I change the datatype to INT which i did before it throws me a different error: 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '[filename]' to data type int"
FYI some files have less than 5 numbers for example: 123_dfh.doc or 123rgdsf.doc so when I get first five numbers that it why it is throwing me an error when converting. Any idea how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: throws an error "least is not a recognized built in function" I think its used in Oracle

Comment: Yes, I started using it and forgot to delete it. The CASE statement is the workaround for it. The query has now been corrected. Please retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that you can use to handle filenames that have less than 5 numbers:

```
select 
    ProdFileInfo.* 
FROM ProdFileInfo 
INNER JOIN ProdInfo 
ON ProdInfo.ProdNum = (CASE 
                           WHEN LEN(ProdFileInfo.ProdFile) < 5 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(ProdFileInfo.ProdFile, 1, LEAST(5) AS decimal)
                           ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(ProdFileInfo.ProdFile, 1, 5) AS decimal)
                       END);
```